# I save a DataFrame in Hbase and I get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/TableDescriptor

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I created a project on Apache Spark.

Version:

- scala 2.11.8
- apache spark 2.3.0
- apache hbase 1.2.0
- hortonworks shc 1.1.0.3.1.2.0-4 (the hortonworks connector)

I need to save a simple DataFrame in an HBase table. For this I started HBase 1.2.0 in Docker container (https://github.com/zhao-y/docker-hbase-pseudo) and created the following table:

```
$ hbase(main):002:0> create "table1", "cf1", "cf2", "cf3", "cf4", "cf5", "cf6", "cf7", "cf8"
$ 0 row (s) in 1.4440 seconds
```

To save a DataFrame in Hbase I use: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

- I declared the catalog exactly as in the example
- I created a catalog-based dataframe
- I tried to save dataframe in hbase as in example:

```
dataFrame.write.options(
  Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .save()
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.junit.Test

class SparkTest {
  case class HBaseRecord(
                          col0: String,
                          col1: Boolean,
                          col2: Double,
                          col3: Float,
                          col4: Int,
                          col5: Long,
                          col6: Short,
                          col7: String,
                          col8: Byte)

  object HBaseRecord {
    def apply(i: Int, t: String): HBaseRecord = {
      val s = s"""row${"%03d".format(i)}"""
      HBaseRecord(s,
        i % 2 == 0,
        i.toDouble,
        i.toFloat,
        i,
        i.toLong,
        i.toShort,
        s"String$i: $t",
        i.toByte)
    }
  }

  @Test
  def bar(): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("SparkTest")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.testing.memory", 2147480000)
      .getOrCreate()

    val data = (0 to 255).map { i => HBaseRecord(i, "extra") }

    val dataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data)
    dataFrame.show

    dataFrame.write.options(
      Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
      .save()
  }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/TableDescriptor

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at SparkTest.bar(SparkTest.scala:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:130)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.TableDescriptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("SparkTest")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.testing.memory", 2147480000)
      .getOrCreate()
```

means you are running that in local and your hbase client jar is missing. (if its there in classpath then you can change the scope to `runtime` rather than `compile`)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

if you are using intellij to run locally, you can see hbase client jar is present in the .iml file.

normal way of runnning in cluster or client modes(not local)  would be `hbase claasspath` add it to

```
  export HBASE_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_CLASSPATH:`hbase classpath`
```

which will add all the hbase jars in to the classpath

to see/print all the jars in classpath below will be helpful to understand which jars in your classpath.

```
 def urlsinclasspath(cl: ClassLoader): Array[java.net.URL] = cl match {
    case null => Array()
    case u: java.net.URLClassLoader => u.getURLs() ++ urlsinclasspath(cl.getParent)
    case _ => urlsinclasspath(cl.getParent)
  }
```

Caller would be...

```
  val  urls = urlsinclasspath(getClass.getClassLoader).foreach(println)
```

Comment: was it useful ?

Comment: no, I changed the Hortonworks shc version to 1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 and now it works, anyway thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: may be your new version got that hbase client which has class `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.TableDescriptor` but still answer is valid. since you dont have hbase client in classpath and after upgrade of your platform you got that jar under classpath. Anyways  this `urlsinclasspath ` is very useful for debugging this kind of issues. In general users wont upgrade all the time they will try to fix classpath issues for `ClassDefNotFound`. Cheers!